# pandas -- How to get Series to dict

Tags: python, pandas

now I have this Series:

```
us    2
br    1
be    3
dtype: int64
```

so How get I can a list. as follows:

```
[ { "country": "us", "value": 2},
  { "country": "br", "value": 1},
  { "country": "be", "value": 3}
]
```

thanks

Comment: Technically, how to get a Series to a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 7):

Create `DataFrame` first and then use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (s.rename_axis('country').reset_index(name='value').to_dict('records'))
[{'value': 2, 'country': 'us'}, {'value': 1, 'country': 'br'}, {'value': 3, 'country': 'be'}]
```

`DataFrame` by constructor:

```
print (pd.DataFrame({'country':s.index, 'value':s.values}).to_dict('records'))
[{'value': 2, 'country': 'us'}, {'value': 1, 'country': 'br'}, {'value': 3, 'country': 'be'}]
```

Another solution with `list comprehension`:

```
d = [dict(country=x[0], value=x[1]) for x in s.items()]
print (d)
[{'value': 2, 'country': 'us'}, {'value': 1, 'country': 'br'}, {'value': 3, 'country': 'be'}]
```

Similar solution from piRSquared deleted answer with [`Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html):

```
d = [dict(country=k, value=v) for k, v in s.items()]
```

Comment: You don't need the to `to_dict` in the comprehension.  When called in a dictionary context, the series will act like a dictionary.